# Global toctree shared across pages

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

Lets say I have two *.rst* files, a welcome page (the index) and an API page. I would like them both to have identical toctrees, so it is easy to navigate from the one page to the other.

*index.rst*:

```
Welcome!
========

Welcome to these awesome docs!
```

*api.rst*:

```
API
===

Here is some API stuff...
```

I tried adding a toctree to `index.rst`, something like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   index
   api
```

However then my toctree gets nested:

[image]

I do not only want to add

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   api
```

to *index.rst* and

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   index
```

to *api.rst*, since that means that the sidebar is different between pages.

How do I add a global index to my project? One that is the same no matter which page I am on?

Comment: Remove `index` from the `toctree` as it is self referential and causing the nesting. Does that achieve what you desire?

Comment: No, I guess I wasn't really clear. But I would like each page (index and api) to have the same sidebar. So somehow it needs to self-refer. If I remove index from the toctree it "works", however welcome isn't in the toctree anymore.

Comment: @StevePiercy I edited my post to make it (hopefully) more clear in what I want.

Comment: I am still not clear what you want to achieve. The left-hand navigation is always relative to the currently viewed document, which is by design of `toctree`. If you want the navigation to remain the same, then it must be a single page. Alternatively you could edit the Jinja2 templates with static global navigation.

Comment: @StevePiercy, I was hoping something "out-of-the-box" exists for this. I don't like it when it's one big page. Seems like I will have to fiddle witht he Jinja2 templates :(. Thanks for your help